# .Net core Routing URLEncoded URL not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a .Net core 2.2 WebAPI that works perfectly fine with "normal" style URLs e.g. /api/controller/action/param etc. I have a 3rd party service that does a POST to this API with a URL encoded path and the Asp.Net routing fails to route this request correctly.

The controller is at: .../api/file/uploadFile/{filename}

The POST from the 3rd party is:
".../api%2Ffile%2FuploadFile%2FMaintenanceReport_2019_08_05_17_11_10.html.gz".

Replacing the %2F in the path appears to work as expected:
".../api/file/uploadFile/MaintenanceReport_2019_08_05_17_11_10.html.gz"

The filename is: "MaintenanceReport_2019_08_05_17_11_10.html.gz"

Placing a Route Attribute with %2F instead of "/" sort of works, but looks very messy.

The filename passed into the path is also not resolving correctly as a parameters. I suspect this is due to the file extension being included.

I've searched the net and did not find anything related jumping out at me. Any suggestions/ideas?

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[Route("api%2F[controller]%2F[action]")]
public class FileController : Controller
{
  ...
}
```

I would have thought that the .Net core routing engine would detect the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default path separator in the url generated by the route is `/` .The issue seems that the separator before the parameter which is as part of the path value is not recognized or missing .

If you request the url like  `.../api%2Ffile%2FuploadFile%2FMaintenanceReport_2019_08_05_17_11_10.html.gz` , you could try to use URL Rewriting Middleware like below :

1. In Configure

   ```
   app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
               .Add(RewriteRouteRules.ReWriteRequests)
               );
   ```

2.Custom a class containing ReWriteRequests

```
public class RewriteRouteRules
{
    public static void ReWriteRequests(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Path.Value.Contains("%2F", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Replace("%2F", "/");
        }

    }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Thanks for this, fixed the issue for me.